# Wordpress PHP syntax doesn't seem to be working correctly

Tags: php, query

When I run this wordpress query, instead of the background image showing I just get the end of the div string echoed out? The image string appears in the browser inspector, but not to the screen. Here is the echoed string that shows: ') no-repeat;"> and here is the code:

```
<div class="leftBox">
        <?php 
        $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=jour' );
        // The Loop
        if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->the_post();
            }
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,'thumbnail'); ?>
                <div class="entry-content" style="background: url('<?php echo $thumbnail; ?>') no-repeat;">
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Go to <?php echo the_title(); ?>"><P><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_post_thumbnail()` returns the full html output of the image, including the image `<img />` tags.  You want just the image src.  Try this:

```
<div class="leftBox">
    <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( 'pagename=jour' );
    // The Loop
    if ( $query && $query->have_posts() ) :
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                $img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() ), 'thumbnail' );
                 ?>
                <div class="entry-content" style="background: url('<?php echo esc_url( $img_src ); ?>') no-repeat;">
                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>" title="Go to <?php echo the_title(); ?>"><p><?php the_title(); ?></p></a>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        endwhile;
    endif;
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks darrinb, that works like a charm. The only issue remaining is that the image is being shown in very low resolution. Any thoughts?

Comment: You can choose a different size other  than "thumbnail".  WordPress has a few default sizes: `thumbnail`, `medium`, `medium_large`, `large`, and `full`.

If this resolves your question, be sure to accept the answer.  Thanks!